# Cisco Router - Add a missing MIB file

Tags: cisco, snmp, mib

I have a Cisco 881w, and I would like to setup NBAR in my NetFlow Analyzer.

But it says that my router misses this MIB in order to allow NFA to poll the router with snmp to get NBAR infos.

From the FAQ page of the NetFlow Analyzer website, it responds to my error:

```
Q. I am able to issue the command "ip nbar protocol-discovery" 
   on the router and see the results. But NFA says my router does 
   not support NBAR, Why? 

A. Earlier version of IOS supports NBAR discovery only on router. So you can 
   very well execute the command "ip nbar protocol-discovery" on the router and 
   see the results. But NBAR Protocol Discovery 
   MIB(CISCO-NBAR-PROTOCOL-DISCOVERY-MIB) 
   support came only on later releases. This is needed for 
   collecting data via SNMP. Please verify that whether your 
   router IOS supports CISCO-NBAR-PROTOCOL-DISCOVERY-MIB.
```

The missing MIB is: CISCO-NBAR-PROTOCOL-DISCOVERY-MIB

I found it here: ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-NBAR-PROTOCOL-DISCOVERY-MIB.my

But how can I add this MIB into the router?

The IOS of my router is: c880data-universalk9-mz.151-3.T1.bin

Answer (score 2):

MIB files are not used directly on your router, rather by the software which reads the output. They basically just map the internal numerical codes into (sort of) human readable descriptions.

```
support came only on later releases. This is needed for 
collecting data via SNMP. Please verify that whether your 
router IOS supports CISCO-NBAR-PROTOCOL-DISCOVERY-MIB.
```

The product documentation on the 881w should include a list of applicable SNMP commands and the associated MIB files supported.

I'm not familiar with your netflow analyzer but it would also be possible to be missing the MIB file that you need there. Look at the manual for the netflow analyzer and see if there are any instructions on how to add MIBs. This has mostly been copying the files to the correct directories and one or two commands in the cases I've worked with.

Comment: Tim, it says that this MIB is supported on my router: http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=3888&PlatformSel=183&fsSel=1284 ... So why dont I have access to it?

Comment: It sounds like you might need to install the MIB file for your netflow analyzer.

Comment: How do I do that? The software is called ManageEngine NetFlow Analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't have sufficient license level for the nbar snmp support. Since IOS 15.0 Cisco, in their infinite wisdom) give you access to the feature at a low license level but restrict the SNMP support for that feature to a higher level (I believe its advipservices license for nbar).